# Converting alternation into character class

Tags: regex

Is it possible to do the following alternation in a character class that uses `^`:

```
(^|,)
```

When I tried doing:

```
[\^,] or [,^]
```

It was matching the `,` but not the `^`. Is it not possible to use the `start-of-line` character in a character class (without it meaning "negation" or "^"-literal)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's impossible. The start of the line is a *position* that can be matched, not a character, so it doesn't work in a character class. You'll have to alternate.

Comment: got it, thank you. Does this apply to all anchors? What about word-boundary?

Comment: That's right - a word boundary isn't a character either, so it doesn't work in a character class. Same for lookaround.